# Using FS and RS in an awk command

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I'm extremely new to Unix and have been looking into this issue for days.

I have the below set of information in a csv file that I need to manipulate through Unix.

```
BEIGE ,   19.50 ,   STYLE ,   05/05/14
BEIGE ,   19.50 ,   STYLE ,   05/06/14
BEIGE ,   19.50 ,   STYLE ,   05/07/14
```

Using an awk command like below I am successfully grabbing the first field of the first line only;

```
l_colour=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} END {print $1}' file)
```

I need to store each field as a variable (l_colour, l_price, l_type, l_in_date) on line one, import into a database then do the same for line two and so on.

Is it possible for me to use FS and RS in the same awk statement?

Please go easy on me.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean with "import into a database"? I guess that part should be another question. Note you can use `NR` as number of line, so for example `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} NR==1{print $1}' file` will print for line 1, etc.

Comment: Once I've managed to store the variables I'll be importing into a database using sqlplus. It's the storing of the variables that is putting a stopper on me. NR seems the best option for me, thank you.

Comment: Note that you can sometimes import data into databases if you provide a specific format, like csv. This could also help.

Comment: for the question ` to use FS and RS in the same awk statement` answer is YES. but regarding your requirement, it may go easier to transform your csv into sql statement? but the requirement is not so clear...

Comment: Note that at the moment, you're not grabbing the first field. This isn't obvious because all of the lines have the same first field. The `END` block will still contain the `$1` from the last record in your file as it is executed once all the records have been processed. In any case, at the moment this seems a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks for all the useful comments. @Kent how do you go about using the FS and RS in the same awk command please?

Comment: @chrisberry86 simply `awk -F'x' -v RS="y" '{code}' inputs`

Comment: @TomFenech do you have a suggestion on the best way for me to store each field as a variable on line one (do something with them), then do the same for lines two and three?

Comment: @TomFenech - wrt `The END block will still contain the $1 from the last record`: per POSIX that's implementation-specific. Some awks will behave that way, others won't.

Comment: @Ed thanks for the clarification. My main point was regarding the use of the `END` block. It appeared that the OP's intention was to process only the first line and then terminate, which wouldn't be the case.

Comment: @chrisberry86 I still fail to see what any of this has to do with `FS` and `RS`, this question would really benefit from some further explanation. What type of database are you trying to insert these values into? Do you explicitly need to do every `insert` one by one?

Comment: @TomFenech I needed the awk to grab each field as a variable on line one, insert into a database, then repeat for the other lines. Using the below answer I've managed to do what I needed to do by combining it with another sed command. Considering I started my Unix work on Monday, I think I'm getting somewhere. Cheers.

Comment: All I was saying is that you're focusing on one part of the process, not the problem as a whole. If we knew all the details, we could probably skip out a few of the intermediate steps and provide something that would be more useful to you in the long run. Glad you've got it sorted anyway, all the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not exactly answer to PO's question but inserting data from cvs to database could be done by something like this:

```
cat file | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/INSERT INTO table(l_colour, l_price, l_type, l_in_date) VALUES(\1);/'
```

output :

```
INSERT INTO table(l_colour, l_price, l_type, l_in_date) VALUES(BEIGE , 19.50 , STYLE , 05/05/14);
INSERT INTO table(l_colour, l_price, l_type, l_in_date) VALUES(BEIGE , 19.50 , STYLE , 05/06/14);
INSERT INTO table(l_colour, l_price, l_type, l_in_date) VALUES(BEIGE , 19.50 , STYLE , 05/07/14);
```

Comment: Although, it's a bit of a useless use of `cat` and `tr`... Extra whitespace in SQL is generally not a problem, so `sed 's/..../' file` would be sufficient...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're hoping to get out of using awk for part of this. For the input you posted you can just do:

```
$ while read -r l_colour c l_price c l_type c l_in_date
do
    echo "now insert \"$l_colour\", \"$l_price\", \"$l_type\", \"$l_in_date\""
done < file
now insert "BEIGE", "19.50", "STYLE", "05/05/14"
now insert "BEIGE", "19.50", "STYLE", "05/06/14"
now insert "BEIGE", "19.50", "STYLE", "05/07/14"
```

Change the `echo` line to whatever your database insertion command is.

If there's more to this question than you've told us so far, google how to store awk output in a bash array.